# String to Array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, yaml

I need my `string`: `"---\n- aaaadddhh ddddggg\n- bbbdddddf ff ddd\n- cccf\n"` to convert to an `array` in Ruby

This is what I want it to be:

```
["aaaadddhh ddddggg", "bbbdddddf ff ddd", "cccf"]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/). Use `YAML.load(str)` to unmarshal it from a string into an object.

```
> require 'yaml'
 => true
> YAML.load "---\n- aaaadddhh ddddggg\n- bbbdddddf ff ddd\n- cccf\n"
 => ["aaaadddhh ddddggg", "bbbdddddf ff ddd", "cccf"]
```

Be aware that there are security risks in unmarshalling arbitrary YAML, so be sure that the source you are passing into it is trusted.

Comment: Make sure that people can't pass arbitrary things into your `YAML.load` call. If you need to be able to accept arbitrary serialized strings to load, I recommend using JSON instead. You could try using the [safe_yaml](https://github.com/dtao/safe_yaml) gem, but I haven't tested it and can't speak personally to how reliable it is.