# Split string by spaces into an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I want to have a user type some words, and get them converted to an array. I want to split by word. Here is an example:

`"15 17 21 46"` → `[15, 17, 21, 46]`

Stuff like `split("")` and `scan` make an array out of every single letter.

I would prefer doing it without using YAML. Also, take note in the example that it doesn't include the spaces but it uses those as breaks between values.

Is it possible to do what I did in the example above where I have a bunch of numbers with spaces and those get converted directly to integers? I feel like the spaces might interrupt it in case I do something like `to_i`.

This question is similar to [String to Array in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699717/string-to-array-in-ruby), but it does not have an answer.

Comment: the argument passed in `.split('')` is actually a delimiter for array elements, so you if you `split(',')`, the input will be split by comma, thus turning every entered sequence of characters separated by commas into a member or an array. To turn the input into integers you can simply `.map(&:to_i)` your array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`String#split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) doesn't actually need an argument if you want to split around whitespaces :

```
"15 17 21 46".split
#=> ["15", "17", "21", "46"]
```

If you want to specify an argument, you need to use a space, not an empty string :

```
"15 17 21 46".split(' ')
#=> ["15", "17", "21", "46"]
```

And if you want to convert those strings to integers :

```
"15 17 21 46".split(' ').map(&:to_i)
#=> [15, 17, 21, 46]
```

Comment: In this example, what does `.map()` do? I know what `to_i` does but why are you using `.map()`?

Comment: @CyanCoding: What is the object I'm calling `map` on? Where is the corresponding documentation? Why wouldn't `"15 17 21 46".split.to_i` work? Those are the questions you should ask yourself anytime you don't know that a method does.

Comment: Readers unfamiliar with `split`: `split` without an argument is equivalent to `split(/\s+/)`, `\s` representing a whitespace character (mainly spaces, tabs (`\t`) and newlines (`\n`), but also carriage returns (`\r`) and form-feeds (`\f`)), so, `"1     2, 3".split #=> [1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 1):

Eric Duminil's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44910887/298607) shows how to split the string on what the contents is not -- spaces. Perfectly valid if you know that your string contains only digits of interest and spaces.

You can also gather the elements based on what you want -- digits vs what you don't want -- the spaces between the digits.

To do that in Ruby, use a regex with `.scan`:

```
> "15 17 21 46".scan(/\d+/)
=> ["15", "17", "21", "46"]
```

Or, if you have numbers embedded in strings that you do not want:

```
> "15 17 21 46 123abc 34".scan(/\b\d+\b/)
=> ["15", "17", "21", "46", "34"]
```

Note that `123` is not included since it is part of the string `123abc` as opposed to:

```
> "15 17 21 46 123abc 34".scan(/\d+/)
=> ["15", "17", "21", "46", "123", "34"]
```

This includes `123` since the word break `\b` was not part of the regex.

If you just split on spaces:

```
> "15 17 21 46 123abc 34".split
=> ["15", "17", "21", "46", "123abc", "34"]
```

What the 'right answer' is is based on your goal and your data.

Then you can convert those values to integers:

```
"15 17 21 46 123abc 34".scan(/\b\d+\b/).map {|s| Integer(s) }
=> [15, 17, 21, 46, 34]
```

Note that I am calling `Integer` vs the more permissive `.to_i`. `Integer` will raise an exception for strings that are not completely converted to an integer vs `to_i` that will convert the first few and silently ignore anything else:

```
> '1.5E+06'.to_i
=> 1
> Integer('1.5E+06')
ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "1.5E+06"
    from (irb):19:in `Integer'
    from (irb):19
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Again, it depends on the strings and your goal to know which is 'right.'